# MessageBox.Show() 'freezes' winforms app, unless hitting ALT

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

This might be a silly question, but I've been looking around and couldn't find a relevant reference to my situation.

I have a C# winforms application, comprised of multiple forms.
When a specific form is open (let's call it form A), and another form tries to show a messageBox, the application seems to freeze.
The situation resolves if I hit the ALT key on the keyboard, in which case the messageBox appears and I can continue.

This works fine with other forms, so I gather the problem is specific to form A, however, I have very little idea on how to approach this.
The form properties don't seem any different from other forms and we create the forms using the designer interface in VS.

I appreciate any type of direction or help regarding this.

Comment: If its specific to form a we would need code to understand where to problem could be. Because having to press alt for it to appear is new to me

Comment: Most probably you don't use the overloaded version of `Show` that accepts the handler of the owner window and the OS incorrectly displays the message, somewhere at the background of the currently active window. Try to pass an explicit value to the very first argument, the `IWin32Window owner` and come back with results. I would post this as an answer but chances are you hit yet another issue, unrelated to this common problem.

Comment: WiktorZychla- I tried adding the owner and the issue is still replicated. 
it's important to note that the same issue doesn't replicate with other forms, just that specific form A, so i doubt the issue is with the messagebox. 
@EpicKip - I would love to share the code, if you could maybe direct me to any type of code that could be relevant to the issue. the 'form A' class is long, and filled with terrors ;)

Comment: @Eli.E I don't know where the problem could be because I don't know the code -> we're in a loop here

Answer (score 0):

Kindly explain where the problem is throughout my use of windows forms i have been always implementing threads or BackgroundWorker in heavy processes.

Comment: I have a form (A) that is shown - activated via a main form.
while form A is opened, I continue work on my main form, performing an action that results in a messageBox.show() command. 
when reaching that point, the messageBox is not appearing and the application appears to be frozen.
This is resolved as I'm hitting the ALT key, at which point, the message box appears as normal.
a few other notes:
1) This doesn't happen with other forms except form A
2) form A is activated via form.show() so i can work with both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

ok, problem solved!
this is how:
On form A, I have a datagridview. As a solution to previous issue, I had a function running on pain for that object. 
That function was calling a refresh on that same object - and here lies the issue - an endless loop, hijacking my application and effectively hiding the messageBox.

Granted, It was a rookie mistake on my part and a bad case of the "I didn't notice".
Hope this helps someone in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

I have got same issue and confirmed below code works.

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello", "Prompt", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
```

Important things are at five and six arguments. These must be

```
MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 
MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly
```

Hope this helps.